# how can i convert all rows into txt file?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, oledbconnection

i already have the code for convertion from .xls to .txt. but the problem is, it only exports the one row and it stops. what do i need to add for the code to read all rows and convert it into txt file?

here is my code below:

```
using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection())
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                cn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + @"C:\Users\jediablaza\Documents\EDIExcel\EDIExcel.xls" + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";";
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from [Sheet1$]";
                using (OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    adp.Fill(dt);
                    using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\jediablaza\Documents\EDIExcel\EDIExcel.txt"))
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                        {

                                wr.WriteLine(row[0] + "\t" + row[1] + "\t" + row[2] + "\t" + row[3] + "\t" + row[4]);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

the output of the text is shows below

```
SHARPDTL    TESTDTL1    TESTDTL2    TESTDTL3    TESTDTL4
```

but the excel file content is

```
SHARPHDR1   TESTDHR1    TESTHDR2    TESTHDR3    TESTHDR4
SHARPDTL    TESTDTL1    TESTDTL2    TESTDTL3    TESTDTL4
```

Comment: Why you are using fixed indexes for `row`?

Comment: hi @AlbertoEstrella, how can i make is inside the loop? im new to this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think problem is in your connection property: `HDR=Yes`.

So the first line would be the header of file.
Change it to `HDR=No`

> "HDR=Yes;" indicates that the first row contains columnnames, not
>   data. "HDR=No;" indicates the opposite.

Reference link: [excel connection](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0/)

Comment: @JediAblaza This looks to be the answer, check this link with more info about it: https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0/. Maybe trying with more rows in the source file you will notice that the first one is skipped.

Comment: "HDR=Yes;" indicates that the first row contains columnnames, not data. "HDR=No;" indicates the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your problem is that you are using fixed indexes in the `foreach` loop.

I tried to fix your code in the next block, I can't guarantee that it will run because it was made on my mobile, use it as reference only.

```
using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection())
    {
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            cn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + @"C:\Users\jediablaza\Documents\EDIExcel\EDIExcel.xls" + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";";
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from [Sheet1$]";
            using (OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adp.Fill(dt);
                using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\jediablaza\Documents\EDIExcel\EDIExcel.txt"))
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                            var strBldr = new StringBuilder();

                            foreach (var col in row.Columns)
                            {
                                strBldr.Append("{col}\t");
                            }

                            wr.WriteLine(strBldr);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I got confused with something, I realize that you only have 5 columns, that's why your are referencing as fixed indexes, the improvement in my answer is just for have dynamic columns size.